# Why is lvalue to rvalue reference binding allowed on g++ 4.4.6?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I'm learning rvalue feature of C++11. C++ Primer 5th edition says that an rvalue reference can only bind to an rvalue, but when I tried to compile this program, it passed, and the output is `1 1`.

I don't understand why. I'm using g++ 4.4.6, and compiled it with

> g++ -Wall -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int &&rr = i;

    rr = 1;
    std::cout << rr << std::endl;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "rvalue reference doesn't bind to lvalues" rule was added fairly late in the C++11 standardization process. Presumably GCC 4.4.6 is implementing an earlier draft of the specification that doesn't have that prohibition.

Comment: Probably time to upgrade your compiler :)

Answer (score 7):

Your code is invalid, an lvalue cannot bind to an rvalue reference just as the book says. [g++5.1 rejects your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e95b25762d2fa701) with the error message

> ```
>  main.cpp:8:16: error: cannot bind 'int' lvalue to 'int&&'
>      int &&rr = i;
>                 ^
> ```

g++4.4.6 was [released](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html) in April, 2011, less than a month after the final draft for C++11 was [approved](http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/). The behavior you're seeing is either a gcc bug, or the behavior specified by some early working draft of the C++11 standard.

The current rule is described in [N2844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2844.html) and implemented in [gcc 4.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40486).

Comment: For the record, VS2013 and VS2015 RC also rejects your code as well.

Comment: You should probably look at the release time of 4.4.0, which was in April 2009.

Comment: [N2118](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2118.html) includes this example: `double&& rd4 = i;     // OK, reference bound to temporary double`

Comment: @o11c [N2844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2844.html#history) then reverted that.

Answer (score 6):

The GCC 4.4 series was first released in [April 2009](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-4.4/), and the trunk was [closed to all but regression and documentation fixes](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2008-11/msg00007.html) well before that, in November 2008.

The rule that prevents rvalue references from binding to lvalues was voted into the standard in March 2009, as the paper [N2844](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2844.html), after being first suggested in December 2008, in the paper [N2812](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2812.html).

Thus, the new rule couldn't possibly be implemented in time for GCC 4.4 (it was in fact implemented for GCC 4.5).

Comment: So when they make releases along a given branch, they don't implement DRs? Or is it that N2844 is not considered a DR since there was no C++11 standard at the time?

Comment: @Praetorian As far as I know, the policy is that only regression and documentation fixes are done.